# Trying to Install hplip3.23.5 on RHEL9.2 x86_64

Tags: linux, rhel, hp

I was trying to install HPLIP 3.23.5 on RHEL 9.2 x86_64 in offline mode scenario. I tried

```
rpm -i hplip-3.23.5-RHEL9-x86_64.rpm
```

but failed and required two dependencies

```
libImageProcessor.so()(64bit) is needed by hplipfull-3.23.5-0.x86_64

libImageProcessor.so(VERS_1.0)(64bit) is needed by hplipfull-3.23.5-0.x86_64
```

So my question is: Is there any possibility to install `hplip` on rhel without internet?

Its urgent

Answer (score 0):

The good way to install packages with dependencies in RHEL is to use `yum`. Command like this ca do the work:

```
yum localinstall hplip-3.23.5-RHEL9-x86_64.rpm
```

If the required packages are not available in standard repos you should add repo where they are available. Or download required packages and use above command adding them to command  line.

And will be better if you install RedHat package, not HP one (they have the same name, only HP have RHEL in the name).
BTW will be good to check the RH solution: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/3370951

Comment: output:
Updating Subscription Management repositories.
Unable to read consumer identity
This system is not registered with an entitlement server. You can use subscription-manager to register.
Error:
Problem: conflicting requests
- nothing provides libImageProcessor.so()(64bit) needed by hplipfull-3.23.5-0.x86_64
- nothing provides libImageProcessor.so(VERS_1.0)(64bit) needed by hplipfull-3.23.5-0.x86_64
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best candidate packages)

Comment: @Ashishm make account in RHN and register this system. And read the last few sentences from my answer.

Comment: @Ashish, or use above command to install from DVD

Comment: hplip was installed but can't detect device. I tried to install hp-plugin but redhatenterpriselinux is not supportable.

Comment: Can you try, if any thing works out.

Comment: @Ashish, the HP software can't be installed on RH 9

Comment: What about version 8, Is there any possibility?

Comment: @Ashish, the last version I saw successful operation of this package is RH 6 :(